# sort G.nodes case insensitive

Tags: python, sorting, networkx, case-insensitive

I want to sort the nodes in my G.nodes with G=nx.Graph case insensitive.

My code is

```
H=nx.Graph()
H.add_nodes_from(sorted(G.nodes(data=True), key=str.lower))
H.add_edges_from(G.edges(data=True))
```

But this leads to:
descriptor 'lower' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'tuple' object

How can I sort case insensitive in a nx.Graph()?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found the answer. It's

```
H = nx.MultiDiGraph()
H.add_nodes_from(sorted(G.nodes(data=True), key=lambda a: (a[0].lower())))
H.add_edges_from(G.edges(data=True))
```